# Show menu inside child component from parent in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have the following Databale Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <DataTable :value="data" responsiveLayout="scroll" :paginator="true"
            paginatorTemplate="FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink CurrentPageReport RowsPerPageDropdown"
            :rows="10" dataKey="id" :rowsPerPageOptions="[10, 25, 50]"
            :currentPageReportTemplate="'Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries'"
            :globalFilterFields="globalFilterFields" v-model:filters="filters" filterDisplay="menu">
            <template #header>
                <div class="flex justify-content-right align-items-center">
                    <span class="p-input-icon-left">
                        <i class="pi pi-search" />
                        <InputText v-model="filters['global'].value" placeholder="Search" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </template>
            <template #empty>
                No appointments found.
            </template>
            <Column v-for="column in columns" :key="column.field" :field="column.field" :header="column.header"
                :sortable="true"></Column>
            <Column header="Status">
                <template #body="{ data }">
                    <span :class="'customer-badge status-' + data.status">{{ data.status }}</span>
                </template>
            </Column>
            <Column header="">
                <template #body="slotProps">
                    <div class="">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        <div>
                            <span>
                                <a href="#"><i class="pi pi-ellipsis-v" @click="emitToggle(slotProps.data.id)"></i></a>
                            </span>
                            <Menu ref="menu" :model="items" :popup="true" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </Column>
        </DataTable>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import DataTable from "primevue/datatable";
import Column from "primevue/column";
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext';
import Menu from 'primevue/menu';
import { FilterMatchMode, FilterOperator } from 'primevue/api';

export default {
    components: {
        DataTable,
        Column,
        InputText,
        Menu,
    },
    props: {
        data: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
        columns: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
        globalFilterFields: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            filters: {
                "global": { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS }
            },
            items: [],
        };
    },
    methods: {
        emitToggle(id) {
            this.$emit('toggle', id);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Now I am using this component inside another component:

```
<DataTableComponent :data="$page.props.appointments" :columns="$page.props.tableColumns":globalFilterFields="$page.props.globalFilterFields" @toggle="toggle" />
```

and `toggle()` method is as follows:

```
methods: {
    toggle(event, appointment_id) {
        this.selected = this.$page['props']['appointments'].find((item) => item.id === appointment_id);
        this.$refs.menu.toggle(event);
    },
}
```

That is the Menu is added in the `DataTableComponent` and I need to show the Menu when the last column in the Datatable is clicked. If I don't separate out the datable and it is inside the Parent component, everything is working fine. But I would like to make this as a common component so that I can pass the data, columns and the menu items to the child component. Now as I am emitting the event, I am reaching in the toggle function in the parent component, but as the `Menu` is in the child, it is not displayed and shows an error. How can correct this /